# How to separate layout and content best?

Tags: php

I want to use the same website layout (header, footer, sidebar, ...) for all webpages. Only the content changes. For the sake of reusability and readability I don't want to include the entire layout stuff each time. A class called `WebsiteFormatter` is supposed to help be out

```
class WebsiteFormatter {

        private $title;
        private $body;

        function addWebsiteTitle($title) {
            $this->title = $title;
        }

        function addWebsiteBody($body) {
            $this->body = $body;
        }

        function getWebsite() {

            // load basic framework from file
            $html = file_get_contents("../sites/hui.php");

            $vars = array(
                '{$title}' => $this->title,
                '{$body}' => $this->body);

            echo strtr($html, $vars);
        }       

    }
```

A random page could look like as follows:

```
    $layout = new WebsiteFormatter();
    $layout->addWebsiteTitle("Foo Barr");

    $body = "<h1> The Holy Grail </h1><p>Once upon a time ...</p>";
    $layout->addWebsiteBody($body);

    echo $layout->getWebsite();
```

In `getWebsite()` the basic layout is loaded. Then placeholders are replaced by the actual content. This works fine, but actually I want to evaluate some PHP code, which is embedded in layout, as well. For example some session data should be displayed in the header and I do not want to introduce placeholders for every tiny attribute.

Is there a **good** way to evaluate such code or is my approach a complete fail?

Comment: Google a template library, there are many. Smarty etc

Comment: I don't see how `strstr()` is working here, I would've thought `str_replace()`.  But you are probably looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php - aother will say evil, but it's perfect in these uses.

Comment: Dont even think about using `eval`. This is a major cause of making your code vulnerable to attacks. build whatever you want and then replace it in the sample php file, even if this could make you rewrite your whole project.

Comment: AbraCadaver, that's "strtr", not "strstr" ... different animal ;)

And +1 for a templating solution ... that's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @rjdown: I've just read a bit about Smarty. Actually it does the same as I do, doesn't it (maybe in a bit more professional way)?  Or is there any new technique that I might have overseen?

Comment: @TechJS: Don't worry. I won't do any evil stuff like that ;-).

Comment: @null yes there are probably a lot of techniques you've overseen. Have a look at the code for the various off-the-shelf engines and see how they do it, then use your own judgement for your project.

Comment: there's no such thing as a "php script". there's only files which have `<?php ... ?>` code blocks within them. If your text file has php code blocks, then simply `include()` it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `include()` to execute the underlaying php script. If you don't want the Output right away, you can redirect the output to a variable and append it to your html-string.

For example:

```
ob_start();
$vars = array(
            '{$title}' => $this->title,
            '{$body}' => $this->body);

include "../sites/hui.php"; //can reference $vars as usual
$buffer= ob_get_contents(); 
ob_end_clean(); 

$html .= $buffer;
```

On a quite similiar Project we did it like this:

```
abstract class Page 
    ...
    private $html;
    public abstract function renderPage();
    ...
    public function parseTemplate($template, $data = array()) {
        ob_start(); //Start output buffering
        include("templates/" . $template . ".php"); //generate output
        $html = ob_get_clean(); //catch output buffer
        return $html; //return rendered html
    }
}
```

(`ob_get_clean` is equal to `ob_get_contents` followed by `ob_end_clean`)

where a *page* extends the `Page`-Class

```
class Dashboard extends Page{
    function renderPage(){
       ...generate data-array
       $this->html .= $this->parseTemplate("dashboard", $data);
    }
 }
```

and `templates/Dashboard.php` just contains dumb usage of the `$data` Array along with html-markup.

Comment: Is $data evaluated in each template file? Where do you include the actual layout i.e. where do you merge layout and data?

Comment: @null in the template files. Something like `<h1>Hello <?=$data["worldString"]?></h1>`. (Results in `<h1>Hello World</h1>` which is then appended to the html-string.)